# I am Unable to Display Images From Firebase storage in staggered view in android can anyone help me regarding this

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have Stored Images in firebase storage with the help of "Upload" button, and i want to show those images in Staggeredview, so can anyone help me regarding this with Coding part,
I have created one Adapter, Staggeredview Layout, Dataclass and i have done coding in Main Activity but i am unable to fetch the images, and for single image I am able to fetch but not multiple images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect? If you're using Kotlin, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).